# Change autodiscover URL in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

For historical reasons such as starting out on a Small Business Server our autodiscover URL has always been `remote.domain.com.`

Are there any implications in changing this to `mail.domain.com`, purchasing a new SSL certificate and amending DNS?

For instance, would Microsoft Outlook clients pick up the new autodiscover URL automatically? What about mobile devices currently using `remote.domain.com` etc.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DNS will handle most of the autodiscovery changes you need.
However, any client that had to manually input the autodiscover URL will have to input these a new.

Try using https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/ and reviewing the steps there. You'll be able to see when and where your autodiscover record is used, to review whether or not you're missing something.

Comment: Is the correct process to change the autodiscover URL to `mail`, add `mail` to DNS and leave the original `remote` in DNS? In this case would Microsoft Outlook update to using `mail` or continue using `remote`? I assume iPhone's etc. that were set up using autodiscover would also update to using `mail`?

Comment: Best practice would be to change the DNS to mail, get a new certificate with mail.domain.com as your subject. Then create a cname to mail from remote.

Comment: I have tried looking online but can't seem to understand the difference between: 1) Having 2 A records `mail` and `remote` pointing to the server and 2) Having 1 A record `mail` pointing to the server and a CNAME record `remote` pointing to `mail`. Can you explain?

Comment: The difference is that when you migrate your mail server, you only need to change a single entry to point to your new mail server. It's just to make the job of managing your DNS entries easier, by creating less A records likely to get orphaned later on.